# WPF StaticResource bound to subproperty

Tags: wpf

I have a class thats created as a resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Model:MyModel x:Key="model" />
</Window.Resources>
```

The `MyModel` class has a cli property named `Foo`. I want the selected value in a combobox to be bound to this property. I thought I could do this but Im getting errors:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Source={StaticResource model.Foo}}" />
```

Heres the error:

```
Cannot find resource named '{model.Foo}'.
```

Where did I go wrong? What extra parameters do I need to specify to properly bind to a subproperty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost have it correct. You want to use a combination of the Binding's Path property and its Source property. So use one of the following (they are equivalent.)

```
{Binding Foo, Source={StaticResource model}}
or
{Binding Path=Foo, Source={StaticResource model}}
```

Hope this helps.